# Bootstrap navbar dropdown and burger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I'm creating a navbar in boostrap and the dropdown, burger, etc. aren't working. By this I mean they are not expanding when clicked on. I have worked with Bootstrap before and haven't encountered this issue in the past. I'm using Bootswatch from a CDN and just to be safe, I also added the Bootstrap CDN after testing with and without it, I still didn't notice a difference.

I'm using ejs templating(none of which is shown here) in case that's useful to solving the issue. I just wanted my code to be in a form that anyone could test without having to use ejs.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=”UTF-8">
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Katex latex renderer-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-D+9gmBxUQogRLqvARvNLmA9hS2x//eK1FhVb9PiU86gmcrBrJAQT8okdJ4LMp2uv" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-483A6DwYfKeDa0Q52fJmxFXkcPCFfnXMoXblOkJ4JcA8zATN6Tm78UNL72AKk+0O" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-yACMu8JWxKzSp/C1YV86pzGiQ/l1YUfE8oPuahJQxzehAjEt2GiQuy/BIvl9KyeF" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Slate Bootswatch theme -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.3/slate/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ywjdn7N8uoxzIfGl7jlEBlqw2BNicOSzZDgo7A2ffvbM24Ct9plRp7KwtaIqZ33j" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>title</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/index.ejs">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Notes
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Lambda Calculus</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Languages and Machines</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logic Programming</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Types and Programming languages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/posts.ejs">Posts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about.ejs">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row bg-light">
      <div class="col-md-auto text-dark">
        <div id="notes">
         <p>PAGE CONTENT</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">&copy; Me. All external content belongs to their respective owners.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're loading bootstrap JS on the page before jQuery - this is almost certainly why it doesn't work. (And it should give you a message in the console to this effect.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to locate you script tags right before the `<body>` tag ends. You can [check this link](https://stevesouders.com/hpws/move-scripts.php) to understand why is better.

Also, you are loading jQuery after Bootstrap links. I modified it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=”UTF-8">
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Katex latex renderer-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-D+9gmBxUQogRLqvARvNLmA9hS2x//eK1FhVb9PiU86gmcrBrJAQT8okdJ4LMp2uv" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-483A6DwYfKeDa0Q52fJmxFXkcPCFfnXMoXblOkJ4JcA8zATN6Tm78UNL72AKk+0O" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.0-rc.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-yACMu8JWxKzSp/C1YV86pzGiQ/l1YUfE8oPuahJQxzehAjEt2GiQuy/BIvl9KyeF" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    

    <!-- Slate Bootswatch theme -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.3/slate/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ywjdn7N8uoxzIfGl7jlEBlqw2BNicOSzZDgo7A2ffvbM24Ct9plRp7KwtaIqZ33j" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>title</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/index.ejs">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Notes
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Lambda Calculus</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Languages and Machines</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logic Programming</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Types and Programming languages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/posts.ejs">Posts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about.ejs">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row bg-light">
      <div class="col-md-auto text-dark">
        <div id="notes">
         <p>PAGE CONTENT</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">&copy; Me. All external content belongs to their respective owners.</span>
    </div>
  </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So that fixed the issue but would you mind elaborating a bit on what your did to fix it? Was reordering the scripts all that was needed?

Comment: @K-Log, as I said before, I moved the jQuery CDN link to the top of the CDN links so it was called before Bootstrap.